# Make Google Maps API "Prefer" the UK?

Tags: google-maps

I have a store locator up and running via [google's own tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html). It works great in the majority of cases but I'm running into trouble with certain searches. For example, if I want to find stores within 25 miles of Lincoln (Lincolnshire, UK), it returns no results. However, if I try "Lincoln, Lincolnshire" I get the results. I presume Google is looking at Lincoln, Nebraska be default.

Is there a way of making it look at the UK places rather than USA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out already. Changed from

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=__KEY__
```

to

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?file=__key__
```

Thanks anyway.. :)